# Why am getting "identifier not defined" even when I have defined @Id property?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity which has an Id property defined. However, on running the code, I get this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Entity 'com.example.demo.model.Book' has no identifier (every '@Entity' class must declare or inherit at least one '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property)

Entity:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;

import lombok.Getter;

@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Getter
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String author;

}
```

BookRepository.java :

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
    List<Book> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

Application.java :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am a beginner in spring. What should I change to resolve this error?

Edit: Link to entire code: https://github.com/silver612/spring-boot-demo

Comment: ATGetter is for a method, its position in Book may be fouling the code! Thinking of it, I haven't seen many (if any) entity classes in that did not start with the @id definition only at the top!

Comment: Please show the import statements in the code example. It could be the wrong `Id` annotation.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant I removed Getter and added this function to Book : public long getId(){ return id; } . Still getting the same error.

Comment: META-INF/persistence.xml.   Do you have one of these, and did you acquire an entity manager, the error is basically saying it cannot find an entity manager    (or mappings) 
  https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entitymanager     nb note also read 4.3 in this.    Also the ATcolumn declarations did not appear tight on your code

Comment: More than that on columns, there is also "schema", a job in rdbms that was given to its admin or db architect.    https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/chapters/schema/Schema.html.     Then there is mapping, particularly in retrieval of data on to one , many to many e.t.c.  UNUSUALY if you want to learn entities for rdbms, particularly Hibernate, TRY to bite off the whole chunk of "entity class source" by writing all you want to query the table with.,sort through each piece to make the DTO and DAO. In effect entity is a schema, not an entities job to be a whole schema.

Comment: @SamuelMarchant Section 6 from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start states that no extra configuration is required. So is the META_INF/persistence.xml file still required?

Comment: Reasonably sure it is , https://nieldw.medium.com/jpa-spring-boot-will-not-search-for-meta-inf-persistence-xml-f28f14444d6d#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20will%20not%20search%20for%20or%20use%20a%20META,the%20persistence%20unit%20name%20there.

Comment: Now I understand two points here, 1. "Simple persistence" bypass of JPA.  And 2. Column declarations is for CRUD create,read,update,delete carried out by methods configured for with dialect. So no SQL query to place in the entity! 'Petstlstance" in this context is the storage by the database, not object persistence in memory.

Comment: Inside an entity, the ATid variable represents a "row" , the other variables represent either and most usually columns (just one row piece of)or resultant columns  (just one row piece of) in a result set, all of those can have a setter and a getter except resultant (use of a special query that e.g. calculates averages) that can only have getter.

Comment: The entity is picked up by libraries from the tutorial and spring with @EntityScan , are the steps followed.   That is why I don't like "spring" , also ATautowired is another part of it , and one final blow to practical DTO DOA and entities with JPA, the tutorial also uses ATrestcontroller , never mind an in memory h2 database.  I'd seriously learn plenty of spring first , or known rdbms, DAO, DTO, entities,SQL, and web services with soap and simple first if I did not know spring.

Comment: The error refers to org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class.  Perhaps that is your error, the tutorial used h2 db, if you want to do hibernate see for a db such as postgre or MySQL and a version of hibernate and do their dto DOA entity tutorials. And presumably a webserver.   The tutorial should not be looking for a hibernate library.

Comment: Sorry I mistook @,Restcontroller for web services, REST is a rule set for transfer of data

Comment: ...of the error, one of the biggest points things being out of the normal without configuration, and not so much as dynamic configuration is @EntityScan in the tutorial and REST paths with Spring ATautwired.    The tutorial more explains the code in terms of framework parts and Spring, it is not an actual practical (ok , so not conventional) DAO. Entity rdbms access.